# How to delete everything on HDD during Windows Installation

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, windows-installation, windows-installer

I want to wipe everything on my PC's hard disk including everything in all the partitions (even `C:\`).

How can I do it WHILE installing Windows 7 and NOT after it is done?

I'm currently in the Install Windows Menu at the part where it asks "Where do you want to install Windows?"

It displays this:
[image]

Not the topic of the question but here's some background:
I'm using a 64GB USB drive that has a Windows 7 32-bit ISO burned on it for installation.

My PC has unfortunately been infected with a Shortcut Virus, which is part of the reason why I want to completely delete everything, as it is with the Nuke From Orbit approach.

Comment: Did you try using "Delete"?

Comment: Well yeah but I was given a warning message and in my current situation I cannot afford to make a mistake at all in installing and formating my device. Paranoid, I know.

Comment: @ronnie you've files in partition2. Check that out.

Comment: What kind of mistake are you worried you'll make?

Comment: You want to get rid of everything so delete all partitions.  What mistake could happen you want to format all partitions and install Windows keeping one of your data

Answer (score 1):

You need to select each partition and then click **Delete** until all of the partitions have been removed. You should end up with a single "unallocated space" entry. Select that and continue the Windows installation from there.

In rare cases after deleting all of the partitions Windows will refuse to install on the remaining free space. Solve this by cancelling the Windows installation, then reboot and try again. It will work on the second attempt.